# decrypted.Skip not in system array(net.2) vb.net

Tags: vb.net, encryption

How to I modify decrypted.Skip to work in net framework 2? this code work fine in net4

```
Dim user As Byte() = decrypted.Skip(2).Take(userLength).ToArray()
Dim passLength As Short = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(BitConverter.ToInt16(decrypted, userLength + 2))
Dim password As Byte() = decrypted.skip(4 + userLength).ToArray()
```

Comment: What is the type of decrypted?

Comment: decrypted is a function of a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try LinqBridge

http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/

It reimplements linq operatos for .net 2.0.